# How can I add Active class to react sidebar

Tags: reactjs

I implemented a sidebar menu with ReactJs.
Now I want that when clicking on a specific link, this link has the active_menu class defined and the others have the default style.

Here is my sidebar in question

[my sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5In8.png)

Here there is the **state** and the **handleClick()** function

```
 state = {
      idUser: parseInt(localStorage.getItem('idUser')),
      user: '',
      active_menu : {
           backgroundColor: '#044b9e',
           paddingTop: '12px',
           
     
       },selected:0,
       inactive_menu : {},
       
     }
     handleClick = (num) => () => {
       this.setState({
         selected:num
       })
       
     };
```

Now this is where I am trying to set the active class for the link that was clicked

```
   <a style={selected == 0 ? active_menu : inactive_menu} onClick={this.handleClick(0)} className='row item_menu_user_' href={`/user`}><bi className="bi  items  bi-person-circle">
    </bi><span className='item'>Mon profil</span></a>
            
    <a style={selected == 1 ? active_menu : inactive_menu} onClick={this.handleClick(1)} className='row item_menu_user_' href={`/user`}><bi className="bi  items  bi-bell-fill">
    </bi> <span className='item'>Notifications</span></a>
            
    <a style={selected == 2 ? active_menu : inactive_menu} onClick={this.handleClick(2)} className='row item_menu_user_'  href={`/listeDemande/${idUser}`}><bi className="bi  items  bi-arrow-up-right-circle">
    </bi><span className='item'>Mes Demandes</span></a>
            
    <a style={selected == 3 ? active_menu : inactive_menu} onClick={this.handleClick(3)} className='row item_menu_user_' href={`/listeQuestion/${idUser}`}><bi className="bi  items  bi-question-circle">
    </bi><span className='item'>Mes Questions</span></a>
```

However, because I initialized **selected** to 0 in the state, even if I click on a link, the value is always 0 which means that there is always the first link that remains active.

Do you have a solution to my problem please?

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick={() => this.handleClick(0)} // or 1 or two ..etc..
```

Comment: I have already done that look at the code